# Accessing lm_sensors remotely?

Tags: linux

I have Installed lm_sensors on my servers.How is it possible to access the sensors remotely on all the servers like HDDTemp that listen's on specific port.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Tahnks

---

Thank you all for your help.I was considering munin.But I am actually interested in writing a perl script to access lm-sensors remotely and then format the output accordingly.I would be very nice if someone could give me a tip on that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use SNMP.

lm-sensors has an own MIB and the data is [exposed through net-snmp](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Net-SNMP_and_lm-sensors_on_Ubuntu_10.04). You can collect it using any decent [monitoring system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) which is capable of collecting SNMP data.

Answer (score 2):

You would probe lm-sensors with a monitoring system, like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). This would give you a graph and many other features.

[This might be useful](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2011/08/munin-and-lm_sensors), if you chose munin. Other network monitoring systems will do it too. If you have multiple servers, I would think about nagios, zabbix etc. They all do the same job, just have to choose the one which suites you.

I personally watch hddtemp and lm-sensors with zabbix on my servers.